# Playwright e2e passing locally but failing on live

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I am facing a weird issue i just wrote this end to end test which is passing locally but failing when it come to deploy.

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { snapshot } from '../../utils/utils';

// navigate to the page, before each test
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/home');
});

// screenshot of initial state
test('load page - fetch data', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
  await expect(page.getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="card-thedataloaded"]', { state: 'visible' });
  await snapshot(page, testInfo, 'Home - Basic');
});
```

I tried different function given by Playwright like toBeDefined() but it works fine on local environment but fails when i tried to deploy it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always include as much info as possible. In your example: to exact test failure location is important. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toBeDefined()` in your case is always true, because it ensures that expect(value) is not undefined.

Try to use `expect with timeout` to check your app's load state. Loading element is unreliable and can be displayed differently locally and remotely.

```js
// screenshot of initial state
test('load page - fetch data', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
  await expect(page.getByTestId("cardard-thedataloaded")).toBeVisible({ timeout: 15_000 });
  await snapshot(page, testInfo, 'Home - Basic');
});
```